# Where is the Skype chat history in Win 10, 2020?

Tags: windows-10, skype

The online sources told me it is in a main.db file under my Skype username under the user folder. However, for the windowsapp win10 version of Skype, I cannot find either a folder named after my skypenmae, or a file called "main.db" in my entire drive.

[image]

Are there anything I did wrong?

Someone suggested that the chat history is now fully online, which is not true because I can still view my full skype chat history when offline.

---

Update:

There is neither main.db nor skype.db in my folder. There is a "database.db" under the "\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c\LocalCache\Roaming\Microsoft\Skype for Store\databases". The "LocalState" folder is empty in my case.

Comment: Use this SQLite DB Browser to view the contents of the db file you found, that file may just be the logs you've been looking for. https://sqlitebrowser.org/

Answer (score 1):

Skype definitely has a copy of chat history online, as well as on your local computer. You can log into Skype online and download your chat history.

https://secure.skype.com/en/data-export

On your local computer, newer Skype versions (Microsoft Skype for Windows 10) store the local chat history in a 'skype.db' database file. This location was posted in 2018, and may have updated since then, but it should be very similar if you look in the Packages directory.

```
%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c\LocalState\<Skype Name>\skype.db
```

skype.db is a standard SQLite database file and can be opened by a suitable SQLite browser.

[Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/skype-chat-history-location-confusion/b6afa10e-1e61-438b-8228-6a5519d9a90c)

You can use PowerShell to locate any files with the extension .db within a directory if you are having difficulty locating the file. Here is an example, run on the C:\Users directory, which might need to be changed to ProgramData or Program Files. As is, you can just paste this into PowerShell to check the Users folder.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Filter *.db | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq '.db' }
```

Comment: In my version (newest win10 appstore Skype), there is no file named "skype.db". I did find another db file in the directory but it is 0KB.

Comment: What was the name of the db file you found and at which path? I pulled that information about the database file from Microsoft, who owns Skype now. They are going to be your best resource for information on Skype specifically.

Comment: Hi, there is no skype.db. Actually, there is a "database.db" under the "\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c\LocalCache\Roaming\Microsoft\Skype for Store\databases". Your source could be the Feb 2019 microsoft post. The LocalState folder is empty in my case.

Comment: On this blog post from just a few days ago, this person found a file called main.db, in Program Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.Skype... and also outlines several steps for finding and removing chat history. https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/how-to-delete-skype-conversations-and-call-history-on-windows-10-and-mac/

Comment: Thank you for that link. I uploaded a screenshot. There is no "main.db" in the folder suggested by that blog post.

Comment: Windows search excludes appdata, programdata, and a number of other system directories by default. If it is going to find it, then you can just use *.db, and search for any filename with a .db extension. You might have better luck and a more thorough search if you search from PowerShell or cmd. I edited the answer with a small powershell script that will find all .db files in a directory.

Comment: Thank you for that update! I tried to search for *.db which only gives the "database.db". I'll try the powershell method soon.